# SMTP server with godaddy

Tags: php, html, email, smtp

Hello there 
I want to know how it is possible to set up a mail server so people can sign up to my site and get their own email account. For example like gmail or hotmail and yahoo. Is this possible I have GoDaddy. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graeme: not really

Have a look at something like http://howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-10.10-maverick-meerkat-ispconfig-2 (or any of the "Perfect Server" tutorials on that site).

My advice - don't go with godaddy. Take a look at someone like [slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com)/[rackspace cloud](http://www.rackspacecloud.com)/[linode](http://www.linode.com)

Answer (score -1):

Sure it's possible, otherwise gmail and hotmail and yahoo wouldn't have been able to do it. But it's a non-trivial (read: difficult) project. Sorry if this sounds condescending, but if you have to ask such a basic question about it, a project of this scope might be beyond you.